# Detecting a shift + click with Jquery on Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to detect a shift click with javascript but for some reason it only works on IE

```
.click(function (e) {
    if (e.shiftKey) {
        Rain();
    }
});
```

this is the code that work for me in IE, how can I detect it on Chrome

Comment: This should work fine on Chrome. Maybe double check that the Rain() function is working and that the event handler is being applied correctly.

Comment: The function works fine

Comment: Have you tried logging the event to console to compare when shift is down then no keys down?  Also, if it's not possible you could try only binding the click event once shift is down, then unbind the click when shift is released?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a defined combo, but you could make it yourself. A (crude) example:

```
<div id="someElement">
    Click me for an alert!
</div>

<script>
var shiftPressed = false;
$(document).keydown(function(event) {
    shiftPressed = event.keyCode==16;
});
$(document).keyup(function(event) {
    if( event.keyCode==16 ){ shiftPressed = false; }
});

$('#someElement').on('click', function(e){
    if( shiftPressed ){
        alert("Shift and click!");
    }
    else{ alert("Nope"); }

});
</script>
```

*You could improve it by only binding the `.keyup()` when the keydown is a shift in order to minimize the number of events. You should add as little logic as possible outside the if statements, as this event gets fired **a lot***

Comment: This is a good idea for logic but like you've said it doesn't work, which is because e.shiftKey doesn't work in the keyup event. You could use e.keyCode === 16 instead.

Comment: Haha yes, was just working on that update. It should now work mostly as expected

Comment: It doesn't detect the event.keyCode either

Comment: What are you testing this in? I've tested it in Chrome and it works for me. Nevertheless, it serves more as an example than a ready2use snippit :)

Comment: My bad. the keyCode does work on Chrome but not on IE

Comment: You might want to use `e.which` then, there is one which works in all browsers

Comment: The orignall answer did worked beside the fact you can't really nest those event like suggested